# Selecting the dropdown value changing the text field value using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Hi i have a form with some dropdowns and text fields .If i am selecting a value from dropdown the text field value should be changed. In dropdown if i am selecting the value as YES then it should display " Not Applicable" value in text field for ( previous_employment ). If selected NO then it should display the blank text field where user can add their own data.

```js
$(document).on("change", "#full_part_time", function() {
  var full_part_time = $(this).val();

  if (full_part_time == "yes") {
    $(".dropdownselection").addClass("hidden");
    $("#full_part_time_details").removeClass("hidden");
  } else {
    $(".dropdownselection").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#full_part_time_details").addClass("hidden");
  }
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  var full_part_time = $("#full_part_time").val();
  if (full_part_time == "yes") {
    $(".dropdownselection").addClass("hidden");
    $("#full_part_time_details").removeClass("hidden");
  } else {
    $(".dropdownselection").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#full_part_time_details").addClass("hidden");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="full_part_time" class="col-sm-12 control-label" style="text-align:left;">49. I do hereby declare that  I am not in full/Part time employment/service not Engaged in any trade/business or profession either previous or at present. </label>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <select name="full_part_time" id="full_part_time">
      <option value="no">no</option>
      <option value="yes">yes</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="hidden" id="full_part_time_details" value=" NOT EMPLOYED ANYWHERE " readonly/>
    <div class="dropdownselection ">
      <p>After my retirement, I am not in full or part time employment or Service not engaged in any trade or business or profession till today.</p>
      <p>Service Candidates shall upload following documents along with service Affidavit. </p>
      <ul style="list-style:none;">
        <li>1. Retirement Order / Service Certificate.</li>
        <li>2. Permission Letter from Employer</li>
        <li>3. Proof of working during study period of LAW</li>
        <li>4. Law T.C.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="previous_employment" class="col-sm-12 control-label" style="text-align:left;">50. Give Particulars of your previous employment or service or trade or business or Profession as under ( enclose necessary proof).</label>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <input type="text" value="Not Applied" name="previous_employment" id="previous_employment" placeholder="Enter your previous employment details">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Jsfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/L2kbjuav/

If i select Yes from the dropdown then it should show the the previous employment field value as " Not Applicable ". If Selected No then the previous employment value should be added by the user.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please edit and REPLACE all PHP with regular rendered HTML or text

Comment: @mplungjan updated the php code wit normal text

Comment: The `hidden` class gets added/removed as defined. What is the content of that class?

Comment: @Lain if i select Yes from the dropdown then it should show the the previous employment field value should show as Not Applicable. If Selected No then the previous emplyment value should be added by the user.

Comment: In that case, remove the attribute `readonly` on *no*. Alas I do not know the proper jquery syntax for it.

Comment: @Lain  <input type="text" class="hidden" id="full_part_time_details" value=" NOT EMPLOYED ANYWHERE " readonly/>
    This should not be changed it should work as usual right now how it is working on column 50( 50. Give Particulars of your previous employment or service or trade or business or Profession as under ( enclose necessary proof). ) this  should be changed based on selection of dropdwn

Answer (score 0):

You can use toggleClass and trigger change on load

```js
$(function() {
  $("#full_part_time").on("change", function() {
    const full = this.value === "yes"
    $(".dropdownselection").toggleClass("hidden", full);
    $("#full_part_time_details").toggleClass("hidden", !full);
    
    $("#previous_employment").val(full ? "NOT APPLICABLE" : "")
    
  }).trigger("change")
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="full_part_time" class="col-sm-12 control-label" style="text-align:left;">49. I do hereby declare that  I am not in full/Part time employment/service not Engaged in any trade/business or profession either previous or at present. </label>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <select id="full_part_time" name="full_part_time">
      <option value="">Please select</option>
      <option value="no" selected>no</option>
      <option value="yes">yes</option>
    </select>
    <input type="radio" name="full_part_time" value "no" id="parttime" />
    <input type="text" class="hidden" id="full_part_time_details" value=" NOT EMPLOYED ANYWHERE " readonly/>
    <div class="dropdownselection hidden">
      <p>After my retirement, I am not in full or part time employment or Service not engaged in any trade or business or profession till today.</p>
      <p>Service Candidates shall upload following documents along with service Affidavit. </p>
      <ul style="list-style:none;">
        <li>1. Retirement Order / Service Certificate.</li>
        <li>2. Permission Letter from Employer</li>
        <li>3. Proof of working during study period of LAW</li>
        <li>4. Law T.C.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="previous_employment" class="col-sm-12 control-label" style="text-align:left;">50. Give Particulars of your previous employment or service or trade or business or Profession as under ( enclose necessary proof).</label>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <input type="text" value="Prev Emp" name="previous_employment" id="previous_employment" placeholder="Enter your previous employment details">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when we select yes then " NOT EMPLOYED ANYWHERE " Section should not be changed.It should e same only the column 50 should be changed based on selection of column 49

Comment: You have enough example coding above to do what you need.

Comment: Text field " NOT EMPLOYEED " should not be changed only this section to be changed 50. Give Particulars of your previous employment or service or trade or business or Profession as under ( enclose necessary proof).

Comment: I have changed it according to my requirement and the data is inserting  fine in database as well but the problem is it is not dispaying the inserted data for the selection of No in dropdown but that value is displaying in inspect element

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: If i am using this function ( const full = this.value === "yes"  ) then the text field is hiding if the condition is no

Comment: So change full to !full and vice versa. I expect you know how to reverse a Boolean

Comment: Listen. I have supplied you with how to test the yes/no how to change the value of a field, how to toggle a class on and off. It is up to you to apply this correctly since it is REALLY hard to figure out what you want if the code I gave you does not do EXACTLY what you need since OYU know what you want and I can only GUESS from your description. "It does not work" is not helpful

Comment: I used the wrong ID in my text, now I use previous_employment instead